# There is no reason for this Unity script to make the sprite move, yet it moves

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Here's the code:

using UnityEngine;

```
public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float strength = 100f;


    void Start () {
        //Initialize the body of the sprite so that forces
        //can be applied.
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {
        //Note2Self: var says this is a variable of unspecified type.
        var touch = new Touch();

        /*
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * strength);
        }*/

        if (Input.anyKey)
            rb.position.Set(0, 100);
    }
}
```

---

I was trying to practice some basic stuff in Unity (I am not used to programming in IDE's at all, we've just used vim in my program so far) when I happened upon this oddity.

First, I didn't understand why the sprite would move at all when there can't be a touch identification, since I haven't actually tested this on a mobile device. So I commented it out and for some reason the sprite still moves. That code shouldn't be doing anything, yet it is.

I have checked to see if the sprite is using the up-to-date script - it is - and I have checked if the script is targeting the correct rigid body and that it is a rigidbody2D. It is.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I looked in the unity documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html
which says that applying a `Rigidbody2D` component to an object will place it under control of the physics engine.

> The Rigidbody2D class essentially provides the same functionality in 2D that the Rigidbody class provides in 3D. Adding a Rigidbody2D component to a sprite puts it under the control of the physics engine. By itself, this means that the sprite will be affected by gravity and can be controlled from scripts using forces.

I have run into issues with rigidbodies on more than one occasion, I suggest you check the `RigidBody2D` component in the unity inspector window and make sure to uncheck use gravity.

Also, you may want to just write a custom script without using a rigidbody. Doing a search on youtube will probably give you exactly what you need for that.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If it is just falling it is probably effected by gravity.

You can turn this off in your script by adding `rb.gravityScale = 0;` at the end of your `Start()` function

OR

by setting it in the editor inside the rigid body component[image]

Comment: Would be better to either check `isKinematic` or toggle the `constraints`.